# unable to update nvarchar(50) having czech letters in it

Tags: sql-server

When I try to update a table as follows

```
update Tisk set Barva = 'černobílý' where Barva = 'cernobílý';
```

the update works but Barva is still `cernobílý`. How can I fix it?

Comment: What is the data type of the `Barva` column?

Comment: @Zhorov `nvarchar(50)`. From python code, I can set `barva` to `černobílý`

Comment: Then you need to prefix the string literals with `N`: `set Barva = N'černobílý' where Barva = N'cernobílý'`

Comment: You also need to check your column collation. It needs to accent-sensitive, if you want that this works reliably.